# Search Source prevent running app after update from Meteor 1.1 to Meteor 1.2

Tags: javascript, node.js, search, meteor

When I tried to update my Meteor app from 1.1 to 1.2 and all associated packages to their latest update, I've encountered a problem that causes my app to fail starting. From what I see, it concerns the package [Search Source](https://github.com/meteorhacks/search-source)

The error I see the on the console is this:

```
W20151024-13:16:43.165(2)? (STDERR) /Users/emindurak/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.9.3zwwyi++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20151024-13:16:43.165(2)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
W20151024-13:16:43.165(2)? (STDERR)                               ^
W20151024-13:16:43.165(2)? (STDERR) TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'methods'
W20151024-13:16:43.165(2)? (STDERR)     at Package (packages/meteorhacks_search-source/packages/meteorhacks_search-source.js:17:1)
W20151024-13:16:43.165(2)? (STDERR)     at Package (packages/meteorhacks_search-source/packages/meteorhacks_search-source.js:80:1)
W20151024-13:16:43.166(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/emindurak/Desktop/deneme1/kitapp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/meteorhacks_search-source.js:101:4
W20151024-13:16:43.166(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/emindurak/Desktop/deneme1/kitapp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/meteorhacks_search-source.js:110:3
W20151024-13:16:43.166(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/emindurak/Desktop/deneme1/kitapp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:242:10
W20151024-13:16:43.166(2)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20151024-13:16:43.166(2)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/emindurak/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.9.3zwwyi++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20151024-13:16:43.166(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/emindurak/Desktop/deneme1/kitapp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:137:5
```

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled and reinstalled the Search Source package, then it started working fine. :)